# Rails 4 Create record with record.id of join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4

I am trying to have a form create a record in my Test table. The record needs to have the id(s) from its join table called questions_tests. Do I need to create the records in questions_tests from the form and then create the tests record? How would you do that?

The Models (not sure if I named the join table correct):

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions_tests
  has_many :questions, :through => :questions_tests
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions_tests
  has_many :tests, :through => :questions_tests
end

class QuestionTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question  
  belongs_to :test
end
```

My schema:

```
create_table "questions", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "content"
  t.string   "question_type"
  t.string   "category"
  t.integer  "product_id"
  t.boolean  "active"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end

add_index "questions", ["product_id", "created_at"], name: "index_questions_on_product_id_and_created_at", using: :btree

create_table "questions_tests", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer "test_id",     null: false
  t.integer "question_id", null: false
end

create_table "tests", force: true do |t|
  t.string  "name"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.string  "type"
  t.string  "category"
  t.string  "description"
end
```

The form should fill in the Test attributes and somehow have the id(s) from questions_tests. Right now **I do not know how to send or create the questions_tests records.**

My form, not sure how to have option to select questions and store them to the tests record. Here, :question_id is undefined but I need to store 2 to 200 of them in the test.

```
<h1>New Test</h1>

  <%= form_for @test do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name, "Test Name" %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "input-lg" %>

  <%= f.label :description, "Description" %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :description, class: "input-lg" %>

  <%= f.label :question_id %><br>
  <%= f.select :question_id, Question.all.collect { |p| [ p.content, p.id ] }, class: "input-lg" %>

  <%= f.label :category %><br>
  <%= f.select :category, [ ["IP Voice Telephony", "ip_voice"], ["IP Video Surveillance", "ip_video_surveillance"], ["IP Video Telephony", "ip_video_telephony"], ["Enterprise Gateways", "enterprise_gateways"], ["Consumer ATAs", "consumer_atas"], ["IP PBX", "ip_pbx"] ], {prompt: "Select Category"}, class: "input-lg" %>

  <%= f.label :type %><br>
  <%= f.select :type, [ ["Beginner", "beginner"], ["Intermediate", "intermediate"], ["Advanced", "advanced"] ], {prompt: "Select Type"}, class: "input-lg" %>

  <br/><br/><br/>
  <%= f.submit "Create Test", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into `fields_for`.

You'll have a `fields_for` block in your form

```
f.fields_for :questions do |question|
   question.select(...)
end`
```

Within this block, you'll have a way to select the questions to add to the test.
There's a gem called [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) that will help you add a "Add question" link to add more questions.

You'll have to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions` in your test model. Then Rails will create the `QuestionTest` itself, you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: So I should not have created a questions_tests table in my DB?

Comment: No, you need one. Rails just hides the "complexity" of creating these join table records, but it doesnt change the fact that they need to exist.

Comment: What you could potentially avoid is having a `QuestionTest` model, and use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. But I personally prefer to do it the way you did.

Comment: I found an example without having the model. But the way I did it is stumping me. http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/working-with-nested-forms-and-a-many-to-many-association-in-rails-4/